# How do I update the recyclerview list in the fragment? (notifyDataSetChanged not working)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

There is a fragment in my project, when you click the recyclerview there, it goes to that item (detail activity opens). There is a like button in detail activity and when you press it, in the upper layer; The recyclerview in fragment needs updating but I couldn't.

[image]

MY CODE: (fragment)

```
    RecyclerView savedRecyclerView;
    SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler;
    SavedAdapter savedAdapter;
    List<SavedModel>  itemModels = new ArrayList<>();
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static SavedFragment instance;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved, container, false);
        instance = this;


        savedRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.savedRecyclerView);


        sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

        itemModels = sqLiteHandler.getSaved();


        LinearLayoutManager mainLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        savedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mainLayoutManager);

        savedAdapter = new SavedAdapter(getContext(), itemModels, "diyet");
        savedRecyclerView.setAdapter(savedAdapter);
        savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }

    public static SavedFragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

   public void refreshFragment() {
        Log.e("TAG_FRAGMENT", "refresh");
        itemModels.clear();
        itemModels = sqLiteHandler.getSaved();
        if (itemModels.isEmpty()) {
            empty_animation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            LinearLayoutManager mainLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
            savedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mainLayoutManager);
            savedAdapter = new SavedAdapter(getContext(), itemModels, "diyet");
            savedRecyclerView.setAdapter(savedAdapter);
            savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
   
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();

     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();

    }
```

I try this but not working

```
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       super.onResume();
   }
```

Detail Activity UnFav Button Click

```
if (SavedFragment.getInstance()!=null){
   SavedFragment.getInstance().refreshFragment();
   Log.e("TAG_FRAGMENT","savednotnull");
}
```

Comment: what have you done when the like button is pressed in the detail activity?

Comment: SavedFragment.getInstance().savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  but not working again

Comment: That won't work unless you modify the list which is given in the adapter

Comment: @Antonio why? It works between activities, why not now? Also when I update the list, the page scrolls back to the beginning. I don't want it.

Comment: you don't have to use static methods or fields. Whenever you return back to fragment `onCreateView` will be called. Here the list from `sqLiteHandler.getSaved();` will be presented to the adapter. So the idea is to change the corresponding item in sqlite from the detail page when the like button is pressed

Comment: What you said is logical, but when I do this between activities, there is no problem. I guess this situation is different for Fragment. How can I update the list in recyclerview without shifting the position or scroll the top

Comment: Do not hold `Fragment` instance in static variable this will cause memory leak . What you are trying to do is simply a usecase of `StartActivityForResult`  or a Local broadcast. better use `StartActivityForResult`

Comment: ok but that doesn't solve my problem. My problem is that the recyclerview list is not updated.

Comment: @Antonio hello I updated my code. I restart the fragment but nothing changes. can you help me?

Comment: @ADM How can I do an action on another activity or fragment from one activity without using a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your `onResume()`:

```
savedAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemModels.size());
```

like this :

```
  @Override
   public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        savedAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemModels.size());
   }
```

Comment: Please give me some time to try

Comment: also in onAttach() you can remove all view and fetch them again and add them to your RecyclerView

Comment: This time the view position will change. I don't want this

Comment: It was fixed when I type everything in oncreateview into onresume. Why did this happen? Is the oncreateview view saving in fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Change in only that item which is click in itemModels list and than do:

```
savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: how will I do? this method does not work // savedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void refreshFragment() {           
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  I already have it in my code. I still don't understand why.  Could it be saving the view?  By the way allowBackup = false

Comment: @Nic3500 What are you thinking? I have recreated the fragment. I'm recreating the top activity but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged **must** be run on the UI Thread, if it doesn't you should force it. Try this where you want to update recyclerview after changing the data, it worked for me when others don't.

```
((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

If it doesn't work, maybe you should review your data, adapter, and recyclerview.